# How to run a command in a new terminal/tab, but stay in original terminal/tab with cli on any OS?

Tags: python, node.js, command-line-interface

Pretend this is my **package.json**

```
{
   doStuff: npm run A && npm run B,
   A: openTerminal && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
   B: doTestStuff
}
```

I want to `npm run doStuff` in a terminal

Script A will open a new terminal or tab and run a python simple server.

Script B will remain in the original terminal/tab and run tests on the served contents from script A.

I'm looking for a universal solution that works on any OS, even if that means running commands that don't work on the target OS to get to the one that does.

Is this possible or am I only dreaming?

Comment: What is your OS? The implementation will be platform specific.

Comment: Thanks [nilsw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5199616/nilsw), I have seen the mac implementations. I apologize for not being more specific, was hoping for a universal solution.

Comment: (Just so you know: to "ping" a user, don't use a link. You can address `nilsw` simply as "@nilsw" – you'll even get a handy popup so you don't have to fully type a long name. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).)

Comment: @Ari what do you mean exactly "universal solution"? What is your target OS?

Comment: @nilsw I mean I want it to work on mac, windows, what have you. Again, i realize this is a big ask, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks @usr2564301

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you can use a tabbed terminal app like [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) on macOS. You can also use AppleScript to launch terminal windows and run specific scripts. The specific implementation will depend on your operating system.

For example, this AppleScript opens a new tab in Terminal:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
```

Another option is to use the Node.js package `ttab`, [available on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab).

Example 1:

```
ttab 'npm run script_name'
```

Example 2:

```
ttab 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888'
```